# Is it possible to write a weakly polymorphism function without involving ref or partial application?

Tags: ocaml, value-restriction

```
let remember =
   let cache = ref None in
    (fun x ->  match !cache with
         | Some y -> y
         | None -> cache := Some x; x)
```

is weakly polymorphism, but involving `ref`.

Any ways to write a weakly polymorphism function **without** involving `ref` or `partial application`?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the value restriction doesn't mention `ref` anywhere. There's nothing particularly special about `ref`, except that (under the relaxed value restriction) it's invariant with respect to subtyping.

Comment: `ref` was a lot more special in SML, which is the context in which the value restriction was originally proposed. In SML records are not mutable, only `ref`s (and arrays?) are. Thus a lot of discussion about the value restriction naturally involves `ref`. Of course in OCaml, `ref` is just a instance of a record with a mutable field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Module abstraction will do it, essentially instructing the compiler to abandon all information about the implementation:

```
module Example : sig
  type 'a t
  val create : unit -> 'a t
end = struct
  type 'a t = int
  let create () = 0
end
```

and the weakly polymorphic result:

```
# let x = Example.create ();;
val x : '_a Example.t = <abstr>
```

(Note that if you wanted polymorphism here, you would use variance annotations to recover it.)

It's also easy to construct examples based on mutable structures other than `ref` (arrays, mutable fields), but that's not very instructive as it is pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with other mutable data structures, like array, bigarray, objects, and other structures, that have construction of the form `create: unit -> 'a t`, or `create: some_type -> 'a t`, so that they can be created without actually proving to a compiler, that they will have a specified type.